# libiconv2 dll is missing on windows 2012

Tags: c++

I try to run application compile on windows 7 with additional dependencies libiconv.lib, ws2_32.lib, Crypt32.lib, libeay32.lib. When I try to run it, application crash with "The program can't be start because libiconv2.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.". I try to install http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm and http://www.mingw.org/ (with all libraries for c++ and c), but this doesn't help at all. Also I try to run all system update.

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Get it from their site and place a copy in your app folder

http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/

Comment: I try that also. But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to make sure that `C:/MinGW/bin` is in your `PATH` system environment variable. ([Instructions  for how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows))